# Measure the amount of characters a RichTextBox can have on a line

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, measure

Given a C# Winforms RichTextBox I would like to know how many characters I can fit on a line. I know what my Font (monospaced characters) and FontSize are.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that measuring one character adds some extra space which inadequately represents the real width of one character.

```
private int CalculateMaxDescriptionLineLength()
{
    Graphics g = _tb.CreateGraphics();
    float twoCharW = g.MeasureString("aa", _tb.Font).Width;
    float oneCharW = g.MeasureString("a", _tb.Font).Width;
    return (int)((float)_tb.Width / (twoCharW - oneCharW));
}
```

Thanks Sergey for putting me on the right path.

Comment: Try to use `TextRenderer.MeasureText`. Since .NET2.0 uses `TextRenderer` (GDI) instead of `Graphics` (GDI+). There are differences between them.

Comment: I tried using TextRenderer but noticed that it returns a Size and not a SizeF which means that rounding error is introduced when measuring the string. That error is then compounded over the width of the textbox resulting in a less accurate answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If your font is monospace, just divide the text box width by the width of one char as measured by [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx):

```
static int GetWidthInChars(int widthInPixels, Font font, Graphics g)
{
    return (int) (widthInPixels / g.MeasureString ("a", font).Width);
}
```